# How to calculate sequential (ordinal) number of a specific weekday in a month in Java

Tags: java, datetime, ordinal

I am trying to determine the sequential ordinal number of a weekday in a month in Java. i.e. if a Friday is the first or 3rd friday of a month.

I can not find a simple way after reading all the things I can find on Java Calendar and posts here. One way I can think of is to determine how many days the first week of this month have in this month and then adjust week_of_month based on what day the day in question is. However, it requires a little complicated calculation. Anyone knows a simple solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just take the day of month, subtract 1, divide by 7, then add 1. The first seven days of the month are *always* the first (Tuesday, Wednesday, ...) whatever day of the week the actual 1st of the month is.

Personally I'd use Joda Time:

```
public int getWeekOfWeekDay(LocalDate date) {
    return ((date.getDayOfMonth() - 1) / 7) + 1;
}
```

... but you could do the same using `Calendar` and fetching the value of the `Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH` field.

EDIT: Actually, I've just noticed that for a change, `java.util.Calendar` is actually simpler than Joda Time - there's a particular field for it! All you need is:

```
int weekOfWeekDay = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH);
```

From the docs for [`DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH):

> Field number for get and set indicating the ordinal number of the day of the week within the current month. Together with the DAY_OF_WEEK field, this uniquely specifies a day within a month. Unlike WEEK_OF_MONTH and WEEK_OF_YEAR, this field's value does not depend on getFirstDayOfWeek() or getMinimalDaysInFirstWeek(). DAY_OF_MONTH 1 through 7 always correspond to DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH 1; 8 through 14 correspond to DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH 2, and so on.

I think I'd probably *still* use the Joda Time version because it's just a much nicer API all round, but if you're *forced* to use `Calendar`, at least you can do this in one shot.